# How to set unique ID for recurring names within column

Tags: r

My data consists of samples, varying in type, on patients over time. This data is over 10197 observations long. A (small) example of my data is:

```
PatientName <- c("Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Smith", "Smith", "Nixon", "Nixon", "Nixon")
SampleType <- c("Venous", "Arterial", "Capillary", "Venous", "Venous", "Venous", "Venous", "Capillary")
DayTested <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday")

df <- data.frame(PatientName, SampleType, DayTested)
```

I now wish to include a unique ID for when there are repeat sample types on the same patient on the same day.

My anticipated output would be:

```
df$ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1)
```

This picks up repeat occurrences of `"Smith"` and `"Nixon"` who have repeat `"Venous"` samples taken on a `"Monday"` designated by the ID = 2. All other ID's would be equal to 1 as they are seperate samples, taken on seperate days.

Is this please possible to do in R?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail.

Comment: What happens if you have extra row `Nixon Venous Tuesday` after 7th row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
df$ID <- with(df, as.integer(ave(as.character(SampleType),
         PatientName, DayTested, FUN = seq_along)))
df$ID
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1
```

Or as @lmo suggested

```
df$ID <- with(df, ave(as.integer(SampleType), PatientName, DayTested, FUN = seq_along))
```

Comment: You could do simplify this a bit `with(df, ave(as.integer(SampleType),
         PatientName, DayTested, FUN = seq_along))`.

Comment: @lmo Thanks, I thought about that earlier,

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% what you want but this gives the desired result.

```
df$ID <- duplicated(df) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

akrun's answer is perfect. Just to show a different way with `dplyr` and the `cumsum` function

```
df %>% mutate(id = 1) %>% group_by(PatientName, SampleType, DayTested) %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(id)) %>% ungroup()
```